# PI as a VPN router for local machines

Tags: networking, vpn

I would like to enable couple of my machines to access the internet through a VPN connection. My idea is that the PI can simply dial in an establish a connection and then route requests from the other machines through it.

I am thinking that setting up a default router of the device to the IP of the PI.

While somehow experienced with command line configuration of multitude of things, could you please point to me to directions on what packages/services I need?

Summary of the setup:

- PI connecting to the internet directly through the default router
- PI creates a VPN connection (OpenVPN) and listens on its local interface for traffic
- PI re-establishes connection on failures
- other network devices have default gateway set to the IP of the PI and all their traffic goes through the VPN, provided that is up (and no internet connection if the VPN is down).

I do not need NAT or DHCP services (DNS can also go through the VPN).

Comment: what's the point? if you use your Pi on your local network to create an outbound connection, why don't you use your other computers to create similar outbound connection directly, saving you the cost of Pi and the headache of software installation and setup? the conventional VPN setup is the computer on your local network, that listens to the *inbound* connections and checks passwords and then let the remote computer to use your local network directly, not vice versa.

Comment: @lenik the point is that I have a multitude of machines that are using the same VPN connection. Also, it is much simpler to configure a single machine than keep changing multiple machines config ensuring they re-dial etc. And you are correct - it is not a standard setup, if it was, I probably would look up tutorial and not be asking

Comment: Not to mention that using a another device to do the routing makes a job of ensuring that ALL traffic goes through  the VPN much simpler

Comment: Some devices are also incapable of connecting to VPNs. These devices include many game consoles, and other devices which don't run standard operating systems that can easily be configured to connect to a VPN.

Comment: @lenik This setup is common in enterprise level networking equipment. It's in-built in routers starting from around $300 upwards.  The OP is looking for a solution for around a 10th of the price... as am I.

Comment: @couling not sure if you are still looking for a solution - but what I did in the  end is to get pfSense router. Solved all my needs and you can pick a cheap used one on Ebay.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same setup as you:

```
Cable modem -> Router (192.168.1.1) +-> Raspberry Pi (192.168.1.11)
                                    |-> iPad (DHCP)
                                    |-> PC (DHCP)
                                    `-> AppleTV (DHCP)
```

First, I changed my network settings (`/etc/network/interfaces`) on the RPi to a static address

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

After that, you need to setup the OpenVPN on the RPi:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

Next, you have to set the config file for the vpn `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`. I used the sample provided by my vpn service (Witopia) and change `dev tun` to `dev tun0` and added `redirect-gateway` at the end.

Next step, modify iptables to allow NAT

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

To make it permanent, save it like this

```
sudo bash
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules
nano /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

Add this to the new file:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Save and make it executable with `chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables`. You now need to enable IP forwarding by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Reboot and the RPi should be connecting to your VPN and be ready to receive incoming traffic. I added a new option to my dhcp service on my router (running OpenWrt) to specify the gateway sent to the client. I added the line `list 'dhcp_option' '3,192.168.1.11'` to the file `/etc/config/dhcp` and rebooted the router. My iPad, PC and AppleTV now connect through the RPi to access external urls.

Sources:

- [Geospoofing with the Raspberry Pi](http://mwmanning.com/2013/02/11/Geospoofing-with-the-Raspberry-Pi.html)
- [Raspberry Pi as a Router](http://qcktech.blogspot.com/2012/08/raspberry-pi-as-router.html)
- [OpenWRT wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp#dhcp.option.example.to.set.an.alternative.default.gateway)

Comment: I just finished setting up a similar configuration last weekend. I also had to add "net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0" to the /etc/sysctl.conf file. Not sure what it does, but the gateway wouldn't work properly without it.

Comment: This worked for me, with one modification: the NAT rule should be `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: I had to install a dns server to get strongswan working. I followed the guide at https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2002171.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN
```

Raspbian should be close enough to Ubuntu for the setup to be the same, and I've just checked that the OpenVPN package is available in the Raspbian repo.

However, note that most VPN instructions will tell you how to create a server for opening your LAN to VPN clients on the internet rather than vice-versa, so you may need to experiment a bit with routing settings.

Comment: Thanks, that bit I understand a bit better - what I am not sure of is how to make the PI listen to connections and forward them through the VPN?

Comment: @petr You just need to run sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 , and have your other machines use the RPI as  its default gateway, and the RPI will happily route.

Answer (score 1):

Currently PPTP only (OpenVPN support coming) - check out my project called DSVR (Domain Specific VPN Router) for the Raspberry Pi.

Blog entry - http://darranboyd.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/selective-vpn-routing-solution-dsvr/

GIThub - https://github.com/dboyd13/DSVR

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is useful, but I'm using VPN on Raspberry Pi from a vpn provider when [I travel out of usa to china](http://vpnarea.com), they have a dd-wrt script which I installed and it worked from first time. So may be you can save yourself a lot of trouble if you look for a provider with already made dd-wrt script. If somebody is curious about the script I can post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I create a OpenVPN Gateway Image for Raspberry Pi.
Hope its helpful :)

http://techfunbln.blogspot.de/2013/09/raspberry-pi-as-openvpn-gateway-with-or.html

best regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setup which is very similar to your need; the only thing you need, installing OpenVPN client and doing some configurations on the Raspbian.
[image]

I described it in my blog; [Setting up VPN Gateway with Raspberry PI](http://ozcan.com/blog/eng/setting-up-vpn-gateway-with-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Right now I dont think that the question "could you please point to me to directions on what packages/services I need?could you please point to me to directions on what packages/services I need?" is addressed in the answer. Could you please elaborate a little more without requiring people to follow the link (which in fact is just the figure again)?

Comment: @Ghanima, thanks for your comment. I have changed my reply.