# RPi as WIFI Access Point and VPN router

Tags: wifi, vpn

I'm trying to set up my RPi as Wifi Access Point and to connect as client to a OpenVPN server.

- The connection to the VPN server works fine as long I use the Midori. I followed this steps: 
   
  [PI as a VPN router for local machines](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7487/pi-as-a-vpn-router-for-local-machines)
- The RPi as Wifi Access Point works fine. I can access the web via my mobile devices connected to my RPi (as long the OpenVPN connection is down). I followed this steps: 
   http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview

However, as soon I start OpenVPN my devices associated with the RPi WIFI no longer can access the web. I assume the problem lies in the routing stuff, but am not sure.

My configuration...
WLAN0 -> connected to the internet router
WLAN1 -> WIFI Access Point

Any help is appreciated as I'm left helpless.
Thanks.

Comment: what shows 'route' after ovpn connection is started?

Comment: Do you want your wifi traffic to also go through this VPN?

Comment: Part 1/2:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.119.74.165   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         timecapsule.loc 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.119.72.1     10.119.74.165   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.119.74.165   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.119.74.165   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0

Comment: Part 2/2:
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
205.164.45.3    timecapsule.loc 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0

Comment: @Gerben Yes I want all traffic to go through this VPN if it's up. However, SSH should not go via VPN

Comment: Now with the wifi AP running route looks like...

Part 1/2
default         10.119.72.177   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         timecapsule.loc 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.119.72.1     10.119.72.177   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.119.72.177   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
69.46.82.11     timecapsule.loc 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0

Comment: Part 2/2:

128.0.0.0       10.119.72.177   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1

Comment: You won't be able to control SSH going through the VPN or not without additional work with iptables, which gets nasty pretty fast. Could you repost the routing information on pastebin.com so that it doesn't loose its formatting?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with my RPI, although my VPN connection was running over the Ethernet port, rather than over a second wireless interface.

I wrote up the details of how I got it working here: http://alphaloop.blogspot.com/2014/01/raspberry-pi-as-vpn-wireless-access.html

The main thing that tripped me up was that I tried to use my local router's DNS for any connected devices, but I found that when the VPN connection was up, all traffic from the devices got routed over the VPN, which effectively meant that they were trying to look up a local IP address on the Internet.

I got round it by setting up bind9 as a DNS server on the RPI and pointing the connected devices to that. It might be worth seeing if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Would you be willing to copy the high points of the article into the answer, to prevent link rot?